# How to enter an output into an array in c

Tags: c

My Code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
    int i;
    int rollDice;
    int firInp;
    int secInp;

    printf("Enter the amount of faces you want your dice to have (MAX=24, MIN=1): ");
    scanf("%d", &firInp);
    printf("Enter the amount of throws you want(MAX=499, MIN=1): ");
    scanf("%d", &secInp);
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    if (((firInp < 25)&&(firInp > 1))&&((secInp < 500)&&(secInp > 1))){

        for(i = 0; i < secInp; i++){
            rollDice = (rand()%firInp) + 1;
            printf("%d \n", rollDice);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Sorry, these numbers don't meet the parameters. Please enter a number in the right parameters.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to have percentages in my code. I think the way to do that is to first enter the output of my code into an array. If there's another way please feel free to let me know.

edit: I want the output to be something like this:

1 3 4 4 4 5
occurrence of 1: 16.6 percent
occurrence of 3: ..and so on

Comment: Shouldn't `(firInp > 1)` be `(firImp > 0)` (and the same for `secImp`) if the minimum value is 1?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: You can create an array that can hold at least `secInp` values or the maximum you defined for `secInp`. Initialize all array elements with 0 and in the loop increment the array element that corresponds to the thrown number and increment the total number. At the end you can calculate the percentage. (I suggest to use variable names that correspond to the meaning, e.g. `faces` instead of `firInp` and `throws` instead of `secInp`.)

Comment: Rather than store all the outputs in an array, you could use an array of counters. This array will be `firImp` elements long (one counter per face). Initialize all the counters to 0 and increment the appropriate element when you roll a number. (Since face values start at 1 and array indices start at 0, you will need to account for the offset by subtracting 1 from the face value to get to the array index.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of integers, with size equals to the numbers of possible values your dice can output. Then you use it as a counter for the number of occurences you get, the index of the array will represent that output value (you can use rollDice-1 since 0 isn't a possible output of the dice), and the value at the index will be the number of occurences.
After you finish rolling the dice you just have to print the percentage like this:

```
 for (int i=0;i<firInp;i++) { // firInp: n_faces = n_possible_values
printf("Occurrence of %d: %.1f percent\n", i+1, ((float)array[i]*100)/(float)secInp);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting close, but not there yet. The values are at least below hundred now. sometimes if there is one "1" out of 6 values, I get the percentage of 1 as hundred. when it should be 16.6

Comment: For a more precise value you should cast to float all the elements of the operation or define them as float since the start. I corrected the answer, take a look.
Now you should properly see the 16.7 (16.66666 is approximated to 16.7) percentage when you have only one occurrence of a number in a six throws example.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of entering the output of the random function in an array you could just use that array as a counter, and incrementing the array at position `rollDice` every time a number appears. Than you could easily extract the percentage by summing all the elements of the array and by dividing each element by that sum.